# Why does Picker stay empty, unless assigning a list directly to it without altering any values in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, list, navigation, maui

Why does my `Picker` control stay empty when adding my own values to its binding property, but it does populate when assigning `CustomSetting.Methods.Split(',').ToList()` *directly*  to its binding property in my viewmodel?

I wish to perform different checks on `CustomSetting.Methods.Split(',').ToList()` list items to determine my own strings to add to `List<strings> Methods` instead. When I do this however, the `Picker` stays empty so there is nothing to select from it.

**ViewModel:**

```
private CustomSetting customSetting;
public CustomSetting CustomSetting
{
    get => customSetting;
    set => SetProperty(ref customSetting, value);
}

private List<string> methods = new();
public List<string> Methods
{
    get => methods;
    set => SetProperty(ref methods, value);
}

public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> Params)
{
    CustomSetting = Params["Setting"] as CustomSetting;
    
    // WORKS:
    this.Methods = CustomSetting.Methods.Split(',').ToList();

    // DOES NOT WORK:
    List<string> methods = CustomSetting.Methods.Split(',').ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.Count; i++)
    {
        switch (methods[i])
        {
            case "value1":
                Methods.Add("MyNewValue1");
                break;
            case "value2":
                Methods.Add("MyNewValue2");
                break;
        }
    }

    // ALSO DOES NOT WORK:
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case "value1":
                Methods.Add("MyNewValue1");
                break;
            case "value2":
                Methods.Add("MyNewValue2");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in my "for" loop, right now I am only adding `methods[i]` to the `Methods` list, but I'd also like to perform other actions on `methods[i]` before adding it to `Methods`.

**Setting model:**

```
public class CustomSetting
{
    public string Methods { get; set; }
}
```

**Picker in XAML**

```
<Picker HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Methods}"
        Title="Choose an option"/>
```

**BaseViewModel**
Just in case this matters, `SetProperty()` looks like this:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected bool SetProperty<TValue>(ref TValue backingField, TValue value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Comparer<TValue>.Default.Compare(backingField, value) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    backingField = value;

    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: when you assign the entire property, it fires a `PropertyChanged` event.  When you add a new item, it does not.  Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` to fix this

Comment: @Jason Many thanks! I never expected an `ObservableCollection` to be needed as `ApplyQueryAttributes` would still run before showing the page. Or so it seemed while I was adding breaking points to debug this. Glad that works!

Comment: What was missing from the original approach, was `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Methods))` at end, to tell XAML that the property had changed. This is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason suggested, you may need `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` to fix the issue as that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> methods = new();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Methods
    {
        get => methods;
        set => SetProperty(ref methods, value);
    }
```